# Same ID error during magento order export

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv, magento

I am having trouble running an order export from my magento store. I keep getting the following error:
`Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "524" already exist`

Research has told me this is due to some bad records in my database, but I cant find any info on what those might be. I have looked for conflicting order numbers but there don't seem to be any.

Does anyone know what the cause of errors like this is and/or how to find/fix the DB errors that cause it?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: @rathinam its been > 5 years. I think so? I vaguely remember finding out this employer had imported records from an old site and thus there was some invalid entries in the DB

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same issue my self, add a group at the end of the collection, for example

```
->group(array('main_table.order.id'));
```